# CSS or JS - Remove default lateral spaces of inline elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, inline, spaces

By default, when an inline HTML element contains a text, and this text break in n-lines, the width of this element automatically pass to occupy all the available width of the parent container. So, if the parent container doesn't have borders or padding, the child inline element will have the same width of its parent. Here is a image to better explanation:

[image]

I'd like to know if there is some way to avoid these default lateral spaces (in red) of inline elements.

```
<div name="Parent Element" style="width:100%;">
    <div name="Inline Element" style="display:inline-block;">
        I have some text here
    </div>
</div>
```

The unique way I could achieve that was by including a `<br>` between every word:

```
<div name="Parent Element" style="width:100%;">
    <div name="Inline Element" style="display:inline-block;">
        I<br>have<br>some<br>text<br>here
    </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't solve my problem at all.
Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "avoid" them? You want the `inline-block` to occupy the full width of the parent?

Comment: I mean, I need the result as  shown on the "Desired Mobile View", not the full width of the parent. But I can't set a fixed width to the inline element.

Answer (score 1):

- inline-blocks will occupy the necessary width to display the contents in one line
- when the parent width is reached, the content wraps, but the width will remain equal to parent's, even if by wrapping the text elements will look like there is some space.

So, using `inline-block` will not get you where you want to get. However, there is a way:

```css
[name="Parent Element"] {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

[name="Inline Element"] {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  max-width: calc(100% - 120px);
}
```

```html
<div name="Parent Element" style="width:100%;">
    <div name="Inline Element" style="display:inline-block;">
        I have some text here
    </div>
</div>
```

Typically, this kind of problem is fixed by simply giving the parent a padding (which forces the child to wrap). Also, if you have more than one child and you want them to have the same width, give them `display:block` instead of `inline-block`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good tip, but I need the width of the inline element to be set according with the text inside it. I'll try another html markup here, I think I have a solution...

Comment: AFAIK, as long as it wraps, you lose control over its width. As in, it's not going backwards. It will remain the maximum width allowed by the currently applying rules. But do let me know if you find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block` will occupy width of its inner content.
So, I would suggest to assign a width to `Inline Element`.

Comment: I need the inline element to automatically adapt its width without remaining white spaces inside it. So, if a sentence breaks in 3 lines, the width of the inline element must be the width of the most larger line. Set a fixed width don't solve my problem.